# Access fields of a Struct in an Object with Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, typedreference

I'm trying to use reflection (ultimately on unknown at compile time) `object` which include `struct`. I've got as far as `TypedReference.MakeTypedReference` but I've hit a wall.

Here's my Class and Struct

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Id;
    public Money Amount; 
}

public struct Money
{
    public int Vaule;
    public string Code;
}
```

And here is how I am trying to set "Code" of "Amount" in MyObject using reflection. As I mention above, I'm looking for a solution which does not know about these types at compile time (that would be too easy!)

Here's the code I have so far (I've used [0], [1] to make the code simpler)

```
var obj = new MyObject() { Id = 1 };
obj.Amount.Vaule = 10;
obj.Amount.Code = "ABC";

FieldInfo[] objFields = obj.GetType().GetFields();
FieldInfo[] moneyFields = objFields[1].GetValue(obj).GetType().GetFields();

List<FieldInfo> fields = new List<FieldInfo>() { objFields[1] };
fields.AddRange( moneyFields );

TypedReference typeRef = TypedReference.MakeTypedReference( 
                           objFields[1].GetValue( obj ), fields.ToArray() );

moneyFields[1].SetValueDirect( typeRef, "XXX" );
```

The TypedReference.MakeTypedReference blows up with; "FieldInfo does not match the target Type." Likewise if I just pass `objFields[1]`. And if pass just `moneyFields` I get "TypedReferences cannot be redefined as primitives."

**Why?** Let's say I'm creating Random test fixtures and want to populate class fields with random data :)

Comment: Are you saying that at compile time you don't know if its using MyObject or Money, so it needs to detect which object is being used and read/write the property accordingly?

Comment: How about using AutoFixture and getting out of the reflection Rube Goldberg machines business? (Though wrt `struct`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930963/creating-a-struct-with-autofixture-throws-no-public-constructor-error) (have not run into any need for `MakeTypedReference` professionally and have to say something as I happened to actually be watching the tweet stream for once, sry!)

Comment: @RubenBartelink - the "why" was simply for reference. Would defo' use AutoFixture if that was what I was doing.

Comment: @activwerx It's purely using reflection on unknown objects and structs. Marc's answer below is the perfect answer for this situation.

Comment: @IanQuigley I'm guessing I definitely wouldn't like to work on the real problem...

Comment: @RubenBartelink the whole thing was a BAD idea, and am following the advice of Marc Gravell and many others. Poco's all the way :) I only dug into it and posted here because I wanted to know the answer academically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to set properties on struct instances using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280506/is-there-a-way-to-set-properties-on-struct-instances-using-reflection)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Frankly, there's no need whatsoever for `TypedReference` here - just a boxed struct should work fine:

```
    var amountField = obj.GetType().GetField("Amount");
    object money = amountField.GetValue(obj);
    var codeField = money.GetType().GetField("Code");
    codeField.SetValue(money, "XXX");
    amountField.SetValue(obj, money);
```

However! I will advise you of a few things:

- public fields instead of properties are not usually a good idea; that will often bite you later
- mutable structs (i.e. structs that can be changed after creation) are *almost never* a good idea, and will bite even more often, and bite harder
- combining mutable structs and public fields compounds it, but making it very problematic to change later

Comment: @Ian just please note the bullet points... this is not a great idea

Comment: @MarcGravell Can you please explain (or give a link where I can learn from) why boxing is needed for using reflection on struct. Other than boxing rest of the steps are same as a regular reflection.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ because all the reflection APIs take `object` as their input.

Comment: @Marc Isn't struct an object too? Inheritance chain is Object -> ValueType -> struct right?

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ it can **behave** as an object, via boxing. Until then: no, it isn't an object in the "heap" sense or the OO sense.