# Setting nested properties via an Expression

Tags: c#, properties, lambda, linq-expressions, propertyinfo

I have the following object:

```
public class ContactImport { 
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public Contact Contact {get;set;}
    public Company Company {get;set;}
    public Address Address {get;set;}
}
```

I want to be able to set the properties on the the nested objects dynamically based on an expression passed in (`Expression<Func<T, dynamic>>`).

To do this I have the following method, this works fine for setting properties on the top level object (such as Id) but fails when trying to set anything on the nested objects (such as Contact.FirstName)

```
public static void SetPropertyValue<T, TProp>(this T target, Expression<Func<T, TProp>> member, TProp value) {
    var selectorExpr = (MemberExpression)(member.Body is UnaryExpression ? ((UnaryExpression)member.Body).Operand : member.Body);
    if (selectorExpr != null) {
        var property = selectorExpr.Member as PropertyInfo;
        if (property != null) {
            property.SetValue(target, value);
        }
     }
 }
```

It looks like it's trying to set the property on the top level object but can't. I take it this is possible but I'm unsure how to achieve it with what I currently have.

The `SetPropertyValue` method is invoke like this:

```
public class ImportCheck<T> {

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public bool Required { get; set; }
    public int? MinLength { get; set; }
    public int? MaxLength { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Expression<Func<T, dynamic>> AssociatedProperty { get; set; }
}


    T pt = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    foreach (var m in mapping) {
        pt.SetPropertyValue(m.AssociatedProperty, Convert.ChangeType(m.Value, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(m.Type) ?? m.Type));
    }
```

In the above example `T` is `ContactImport`, `m.AssociatedProperty` is the expression and `mapping` is a `List<ImportCheck<ContactImport>>`.

**Update**

My issue seems to boil down to the fact that the expression being passed into `SetPropertyValue` has a return type of `dynamic`. If this is set to `int` and the property on the nested object is an `int` then it all works. The problem I have then is that I need to explicitly set the result of the expression to match the type of the target property. This however leaves me with another issue in that I need a list of `ImportCheck`s with the possibility of each `Expression<Func<T,dynamic>>` having a different return type.

Comment: Please show a sample invocation of `SetPropertyValue`.

Comment: Why you don't use SetPropertyValue ,directly? like: `ContactImport.Address.SetPropertyValue(c => c.id, 5)' ?

Comment: I have taken a string before to build a property expression, https://github.com/tbd-develop/roastpotato/blob/master/server/dotnet/RoastPotato.Recipes/Infrastructure/RecipeExtensions.cs it wouldn't be too hard to adapt this to give you an expression to set.

Comment: "Nested properties" generally implies recursion. If you can provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates your question, it would be feasible to provide an actual answer. In the meantime, [my answer to this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30333434) might give you some ideas about how to proceed. (It uses reflection instead of expressions and is specifically about value types, but the basic concepts are the same).

Comment: @AliAdlavaran I can't do that as it's a generic method which is why I use the expression, this way I can use the same function for multiple different import types.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Hope the above edit helps the `AssociatedProperty` would be set using something like `x=>x.Contact.FirstName`